# VueJS SPA not loading properly on Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, vue.js

For some reason, content is not being displayed on the website if viewed from the microsoft edge browser. The background is loaded, which is loaded through HTML, but the parts loaded with Vue do not get displayed and i dont understand why.

I have no idea where to start to debug this.

```
    <div class="nk-main">
            <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
    </div>
```

In the console, i get these errors on Microsoft Edge:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzAJE.jpg

$store is the VueX variable. And the *this* error I dont understand.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this or how I can further debug the issue?

Comment: somewhere in the templates you have `attr="this.$store...."` instead of  `attr="$store...."`

Answer (score 0):

I think @birdspider answered your question. In your Vue.js templates you referencing to Vuex store like this `this.$store.state.blabla` instead of `$store.state.blabla`. This happen because `this` keyword in template is undefined. When you access your variables in template you have to dont use like `{{this.variable}}`, just `{{variable}}`, declared in `data()` setction.